# Inherit from parent controller or use concerns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-organization

I have five controllers that share common code. Is it best to let them inherit from a parent controller, or use concerns? For example:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, :set_project
  layout 'projects'
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, :set_project
  layout 'projects'
end

# three other controllers, etc...
```

I could let the controllers inherit from one controller that declares the `before_actions` and the `layout`, or I could stuff the common code into a concern.

What's the criteria from one choice or the other? Is it defined?

Answer (score 4):

My rule of thumb is:

If the controllers share the same namespace in the URL (for example `/projects/...` or `/admin/...`), than I use inheritance from an `Projects::BaseController` or `Admin::BaseController`.

If they just share methods or declarations and do not share a namespace, than I use mixins.

And sometimes I prefer duplicated code. Because code in place is easier to understand than a mixin with a meaningless name. Do you have a good name for a concern that covers `authentication` *and* `layout`?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I use mixins for adding features and inheritance for customizing features.

e.g.:
If I need to override `current_user` I choose inheritance. If I got only some shared methods, then I choose mixins.